# How to get more than 30 badges in less than 10 minutes?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I just noticed our [t31os](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31073/t31os) was flooded with badges:

[image]

I think he deserved these badges, but I want to understand why he got all in one rush.

For example [this organizer badge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/5/organizer?userid=31073) for an [edit from 2011](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6004/can-i-display-submenus-in-groups-using-wp-list-pages) comes a little bit … late. Many others too. What happened here? Why took it so long to get these badges, and did he get all in such a short time? Is this a bug?

Comment: @t31os just logged in to StackExchange via the FourSquare Auth system. But Foursquare interprets _login_ as _checkin_ and so he became mayor.

Comment: what @t31os is the mayor for WPSE? Ousted he will be.

Comment: wow. I didn´t think someone is really paying any attention to , or bother looking at those badges.. I guess your avatar of "the all-seeing eye" is indeed justified  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a merge - the new user got the badges of the old one.

Comment: I just noticed, the user now has two _Yearling_ badges (both on meta and main). I absolutely don't want to do any harm here, but shouldn't those _one-time badges_ get checked for duplicates when merging accounts? Or do you get that particular badge once per year?